# Github Webhook With Jenkins return 302 Found

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, ngrok, git-webhooks

I set up localhost jenkins, using ngrok to expose my jenkins to github.
I didn't set up any credentials.
When I test delivery from webhook, it shows 302 not found.
Response:

```
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 02:09:22 GMT
Location: http://056b05cb.ngrok.io/github-webhook/
Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Request:

```
Headers
Request URL: http://056b05cb.ngrok.io/github-webhook
Request method: POST
content-type: application/json
Expect: 
User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/d5b13bc
X-GitHub-Delivery: bdc31e52-4115-11e8-9e6b-c7d083151290
X-GitHub-Event: push
Payload
{
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "before": "14e1265dc10ef64c93ee7791db7fa9ccef63279f",
  "after": "1f51b991d10af7c2b8fb4bc4c44417a57cf7bb56",
  "created": false,
  "deleted": false,
  "forced": false,
  "base_ref": null,
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 103):

Just got hit by the same issue.  It appears that you are using the url:
http://056b05cb.ngrok.io/github-webhook

Simply switch it to http://056b05cb.ngrok.io/github-webhook/ (notice the trailing `/`)

If you hit the url without the `/` on a browser, it will get a 302 and the browser will simply redirect.  But the webhook does not follow redirects, so it simply tells you what the response was, which was a 302 redirect.

Comment: It was exactly my issue! Thank you!

Comment: Jesus, what a nasty one. Thanks for this. I was scratching my head for a while

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Wish it was documented better on jenkins/github integration side!

Comment: Damn. The guide I was going though had the slash too. Me: nahh I don't need it. smh.

Comment: Thank god I found this answer before I spent hours trying to figure this out!

Comment: I also ran into this problem, thank god I found this answer! Again, Stack Overflow is my god!

Comment: This works. However i had to delete the Webhook and re-do it with trailing / to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

Please edit your hook jenkins with https://domain/github-webhook/

> Notice the trailing / in the last url

Answer (score 1):

due to "/" it will throw HTTP status code 302 error, please removed old web-hook and add new one with "/"

Example : http://3.131.67.206:8080/github-webhook/

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, make sure you're adding the trailing slash to your Webhook settings *in GitHub* (it may or not be important to also ensure that there is a trailing slash in you Jenkins instance settings, but the default value does have one).