# Github webhook with local Jenkins and ngrok

Tags: jenkins, http-status-code-302, ngrok

I have Jenkins set up locally and I am using ngrok to create a tunnel. I know it is working because if I put the url from the session in my browser it redirects to my local Jenkins dashboard. I also get 200 messages in my Terminal window:

```
POST /ajaxBuildQueue           200 OK                                                                            
POST /ajaxExecutors            200 OK                                                                            
POST /ajaxExecutors            200 OK                                                                            
POST /ajaxBuildQueue           200 OK
```

but when I go to my Github repo and set up the webhook I get a 302 error:

```
POST /github-webhook           302 Found                                                                         
GET  /github-webhook/          405 Method Not Allowed                                                            
POST /github-webhook           302 Found
```

I am using this URL for my payload:

```
http://9xxxxxx9.ngrok.io/github-webhook
```

I was getting the no bread crumbs error but I turned off CSRF in Jenkins and that seemed to resolve that issue. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Of course right after I post this question I find the answer on SO, the internet gods hate me. The answer is to add a trailing / to the webhook url: http://9xxxxxx9.ngrok.io/github-webhook/

Comment: The original question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848884/github-webhook-with-jenkins-return-302-notfound. This can be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @Pruitlgoe. You are life saver