# Github Webhook returned 302 error while linking with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, github-webhook

Request URL: http://13.234.113.124:8080/github-webhook
Request method: POST
Accept: */*
content-type: application/json
User-Agent: GitHub-Hookshot/bfdfc6c
X-GitHub-Delivery: 662b46c0-20ac-11ee-8cdf-33388f50e0ef
X-GitHub-Event: ping
X-GitHub-Hook-ID: 423745709
X-GitHub-Hook-Installation-Target-ID: 664952734
X-GitHub-Hook-Installation-Target-Type: repository

35

I set up localhost jenkins in EC2 to expose my jenkins to github. I didn't set up any credentials. When I test delivery from webhook, it shows 302 not found. Response:

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a "302 error"/"302 not found"? 302 is a redirect, not an error and especially not "Not found" (that's 404). Funnily enough, 302 is actually called "Found". Maybe you should try checking where it redirects to and using that URL instead. Maybe append a `/` to the URL so you get `http://13.234.113.124:8080/github-webhook/` (see [Github Webhook With Jenkins return 302 Found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49848884)). Aside from that, I want to note that HTTP is not a secure protocol...